# Using ErrorProvider and disabling buttons at the same time

Tags: c#, validation

I like red exclamation marks from ErrorProvider, and I want to use it to show the user where the problem is. I also have a requirement that my Update button must be disabled if data in form is invalid. I disable/enable Update button on TextChanged events of all text boxes. ErrorProvider should be employed from Validating events of all text boxes.

Now the problem: when entering incorrect data in last text box Update button will still be disabled, but ErrorProvider will not be shown because user had not left the control. What can I do in this case? How to minimize confusion from User, who will surely ask "why is Update disabled, but no exclamation marks anywhere on window"?

Comment: Just a guess: validate the last textbox on the TextChanged event.

Comment: That would show an error to the user while user has not finished with entering data. It's sub-optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate the last textbox (or all) on the TextChanged event. In order to wait for the user entering something worth validating you can:

1. wait for a given minimal number of entered characters before
   enabling validation on TextChanged, or
2. start a timer on TextChanged - and restart it on each TextChanged event - with an interval of, say, 3 seconds, and when this timer fires - and the textbox is not empty - you can do the validation.

Comment: In the end I did both. Separated immediate and delayed checks, former performed on TextChanged, latter on timer set in TextChanged and also in Validating. Minimal number of chars is one of delayed checks. The button is enabled on TextChanged, but with both kinds of checks.